# finding out an average percentage

Tags: percentages

If 70% of the adult males of a community have brown eyes 75% have dark hair 85% are over 5 feet 8 inches tall and 90 % weigh over 140 kgs what is the least percent of people having all four characteristics ? Is it 15% 20% 18% or 24%? 
       I cannot understand the question well at least not as clearly as to figure out the first step towards solving it.

Answer (score 0):

The word "least" sounds strange to me. Subjectivly I would say there is a possibility that none of the persons have all the four characteristics.

But in common when you treat the characteristics as independent, you can multiply their single possibilities, to get the "most likely" percentage.

$$P=70\%\cdot75\%\cdot 85\%\cdot90\%\approx 40\%$$

Comment: You ought to choose from the options above.